# Salesforce1 Mobile Visualforce Page Padding/Gap

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, tab

I have created a VisualForce page that I want to use for a Salesforce1 mobile quick action or a Salesforce1 mobile tab. But when I run this on my iPhone there is padding applied all around the VisualForce page. Any idea how to remove it?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Visualforce Page code:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true"  showHeader="false" showChat="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="true" doctype="html-5.0">

<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/> 
</head>


<link href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1444933246000/Theme3/default/gc/chatterCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1444933246000/Theme3/default/gc/zen-container.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>

.forceChatterAlohaPagePost .pageWrapper, body{
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

</style>


<chatter:newsfeed />

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Share your vf code so that we understand more